# Solution of differential equation with power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$x^{2}y''+xy'+y=0$

I tried to solve this with the power series method but I can't make the $a_{n+1}$ appear in my new equation..

Here's my solution:

$t^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n} t^{n-2}+t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^n=0$

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n} t^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^n=0$

If I try to change the index from 2 and 1 to zero the $t^{n}$ gets messed up

If I add sepperately the sum for $n=0,n=1$ to shift the index of the sums, the $a_{n+1}$ doesn't appear

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n} t^{n}+a_{1}t+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n}+a_{0}+a_{1}t+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}t^n=0$

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need a shifted power series
$$
y(x)=\sum a_n x^{n+r}
$$
Then you should get the condition that $r^2+1=0$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>0$ so that a solution basis is $x^{\pm i}$ or $\cos(\ln x), \sin(\ln x)$.

You could also directly identify the equation as a Euler differential equation and start with the appropriate trial solution $y=x^m$.